# Cannot kill std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a program that I need to run a thread in. The problem is whenever I try to kill this thread from either inside the thread or outside the thread I get a "error 6 - invalid handle" error

```
class myclass
{
public:
    static myclass* inst()
    {
        if (oInst == nullptr) oInst = new myclass;
        return oInst;
    };
    void main();

    void start();


    void ex_stop()
    {
        //HANDLE Stopper = Killer.native_handle();
        //TerminateThread(Stopper, 0);
    }
}
private:
    std::thread Killer;

}

void myclass::start()
{
    Killer = std::thread(&myclass::ex_main, this);
    Killer.detach();
}

void myclass::main()
{
    ...
    if (0 == TerminateThread(Killer.native_handle(), 0))
    {
            char error[200];


            sprintf(error, "error %i\n", GetLastError());

            printf(error);
    }
```

This is how I start the class/thread

```
    myclass::inst()->start();
```

I've also tried making std::thread Killer an extern and declaring it in my .cpp and .h files, this way I can access it from outside the class, but I still get the same "error 6, invalid thread handle" error.

Can someone please tell me what's wrong with this code? Thanks

Comment: Don't 'terminate' threads. Ever.  If the thread has a shared resource locked (maybe inside new) and it's killed, the resource will never be unlocked; and your program might just decide to hang

Comment: OK, so do you know how to make the above code work?

Comment: have you considered not detaching? It calls `CloseHandle` in the VisualC++ stdlib implementation

Comment: Why do you need to? Both detaching and keep operating on the thread are kind of contradictory

Comment: Thanks PeterT, I removed the call to .detach() but now the thread doesn't run at all. Any way I can solve that? But yes removing the call to .detach fixes the problem but I think it's required in this code.

Comment: @tomtimmer again, why do you think it's required? Maybe now you're killing the thread before it does what it's supposed to?

Comment: if you're calling `start` multiple times then detach after you've killed the the thread not before. But be aware that killing a thread this way is just asking for trouble

Comment: After playing around with it at first glance I think your advice is correct PeterT, I'll report back but give you a big thanks beforehand!

Comment: For clarity, when should I use detach()? Is there a C winAPI equivalent of C++ detach?

Answer (score 1):

The usual way of having a worker thread set up is to put it into a loop, and on each loop check to see if a boolean atomic has been changed ... something that would look like (but this probably doesn't compile straight off; the threadMain will probably need binding)

```
class myThreadJob {
  public:

  myThreadJob(): 
    doRun(true),
    thread(threadMain)
  {}

  void threadMain() {
      while (doRun) {...}
  }

  void stop() {
      doRun = false;
      thread.join();
  }

  private:
  std::atomic<bool> doRun;
  std::thread thread;
}
```

You've not said if your thread is a will do many tasks in a queue, or if it's a one off job that it's doing, but in any case if it's expected to be a long lived thread, it should check periodically that it can still run.

Because you've called detach() on your thread, your thread is no longer associated with your process.  You can think of detach() as a declaration that the thread does not need anything local to the creating thread.
You are not allowed to join it; and you're expecting it to run to termination.

Comment: Interesting, I'll try it. But that doesn't answer my main question - what I am doing wrong in the original code that is giving an invalid handle, error 6. Even if I wanted to use TerminateThread I should be able to, so there is a coding error in my code and I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach
when you call detach, you no longer own that thread, and therefor can not terminate it